# how to check if parameter is passed to me from console?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, filesystems

i'm a new in node js and i have a home task to write a simple program on node js for search file by extension and size.

if i pass minsize parameter it works

```
"execution": "node searchFile1.js   --PATTERN=.mkv --MIN-SIZE=4G"
```

but also i have a case without min size parametr

```
"execution": "node searchFile1.js   --PATTERN=.mkv "
```

in this case i have an error

```
return params.map(i => regexp.exec(i)).find(i => i)[1]
TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
```

How can i fix this that my program work with parameter min size and without?

```
const toString = regexp => {
    const [node, executable, ...params] = process.argv;
    return params.map(i => regexp.exec(i)).find(i => i)[1]
}

const PATTERN_REGEX = /--PATTERN=(.*)/i;

let ext = toString(PATTERN_REGEX)


const toNumber = regexp => {
    const [node, executable, ...params] = process.argv;
    return (params.map(i => regexp.exec(i)).find(i => i)[1])
}

const getSize = (fileSize) => {
    let size = (/(\d+)([a-z]?)/i.exec(fileSize)[1]);
    let unit = (/(\d+)([a-z]?)/i.exec(fileSize)[2]);
    let sizeInB;
    switch (unit) {
        case "G":
            sizeInB = size * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
            break;
        case "M":
            sizeInB = size * 1024 * 1024;
            break;
        case "K":
            sizeInB = size * 1024;
            break;
        default:
            sizeInB = size
    }
    return sizeInB
}


const MIN_SIZE_REGEX = /--MIN-SIZE=(.*)/i;


let minSize = getSize(toNumber(MIN_SIZE_REGEX)) // get size on bytes to check stat.size
```

Comment: `params.map(i => regexp.exec(i)).find(i => i)[1]` I'm not sure why you use the index here. Presumably `find` gets you an array, so how are you sure that the second one is the correct one? Can't you just `.find` again?

Comment: i use index because  find give my an array with ["--MIN-SIZE=4G","4G"] i take [1]// 4G and work wit it

Answer (score 0):

**!! THIS IS NOT EXACTLY YOUR ANSWER**

In node.js you can also set environment variable. You can make use of it as well.

**Example:**

Run command like this: `PATTERN=.mkv MIN_SIZE=4G node searchFile1.js`

Access it like this: `process.env.PATTERN`, `process.env.MIN_SIZE`.

Comment: I need the name to start with --

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to divide process into two parts:

1. Parse process.argv into `opts` object.
2. Your custom logic to handle missing or parse existed params

```js
console.log(process.argv);

// convert argv to object, parse only key=value args
function parseParams(params) {
    const parsed = {};
    const kvRegExp = /--([_a-z]+)=([_a-z0-9]+)/i;
    params.forEach(p => {
        const matched = kvRegExp.exec(p);
        if (!matched) return;
        parsed[matched[1]] = matched[2];
    });
    return parsed;
}

// convert filesize str into bytes size
function getSize(fileSize) {
    if (!fileSize) return null; // default value if MIN_SIZE missing
    const sizeRegExp = /(\d+)([a-z]?)/i;
    const matched = sizeRegExp.exec(fileSize);
    if (!matched) return null; // default value if MIN_SIZE in unparsable format
    const [, size, unit] = matched;
    let sizeInB;
    switch (unit) {
        case 'G':
            sizeInB = size * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
            break;
        case 'M':
            sizeInB = size * 1024 * 1024;
            break;
        case 'K':
            sizeInB = size * 1024;
            break;
        default:
            sizeInB = size;
    }
    return sizeInB;
}

// first part - convert key=value strings into object
const [, , ...params] = process.argv;
const opts = parseParams(params);

// second part - extract and parse required key-values
const extension = opts.PATTERN || null; // if PATTERN was parsed in parseParams use parsed value or it will be NULL
const minSize = getSize(opts.MIN_SIZE); // parse MIN_SIZE

console.log(extension);
console.log(minSize);
```